# Parse an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How can I parse an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [file-0] => Array
        (
            [name] => 3676256.zip
            [type] => application/zip
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpKx0Os0
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 18426173
        )

)
```

I already try without success:

```
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $item) {
    echo "$item\n";
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `foreach ($_FILES['file-0'] as $key => $item) {`

Comment: `var_dump($item)` would show you what you need to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $item) {
    echo $item['name']."\n";
    echo $item['type']."\n";
    echo $item['tmp_name']."\n";
}
```

You have associative array and $item is an array.

OR

you can do this:

```
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $item) {
    foreach ($item as $inx => $val) {
        echo $val."\n";
    }
}
```